# How can I take a screenshot of only the client area of a window?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, screenshot

Is there a way or an application to create a screenshot of the actual windows **content** ([client area](http://www.mybestnotes.co.in/vcpp/client-non-client-area.php)) in Windows XP and above?

I mean <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> captures a picture containing the window borders, title and buttons (minimize, maximize, close). I'd like to see only the content of the window.

Is this possible without image editing/cropping?

If I need a 3rd party tool, then free or open source would be preferable. At least a shareware, so I can check that it works for me, before I buy it.

Comment: Not without installing a 3rd party screen capture tool.

Comment: 3rd party tool is ok, as long as it's free or open source

Comment: This has just become a shopping recommendation which is off topic.

Comment: Well, if it's off topic than close it. But for me it's not a shopping problem, it's a tech problem, I can't solve. Also I'm trying to find a solution on Google, and apparently there is none, on the web because this topic is on top of the list.

Comment: @EdgarPE - My post shows how to find it free version!

Comment: @EdgarPE Search for **Greenshot** on Google and its free.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/downloads/) and install it.
2. Open the **Preferences** from the icon in the notification area.

   [image]
3. Enable **Use interactive window capture mode**.

   [image]

Now, when you want to capture the contents of a window, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> and you'll get the option to select which *window* you want to capture.

[image]

Comment: Its a freeware :)

Comment: Not works in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a third party tool. ZapGrab does this for you.

However, if this doesn't meet your requirements, I suggest a Google search for a phrase similar to "screen capture tools" or "screen capture tools XP" as this will give you plenty of options. You could even add the word "free" into the phrase.

Comment: Well thanks, but I need a free or open source tool.

Comment: Well, you never stated this in your OP - I think you need to [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/531883/edit) and make it clear -1

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Vista (except Basic), Windows7 and Windows 8 you have the built in Snipping tool to do this. That is a really good tool for screenshots.

Comment: The OP says XP though.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it on XP too.

Comment: You have to define the area you want to capture, rather than just using a single click to capture the entire window.